# Nagios set higher interval for notifications

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I want to set the interval of each notification sent by my nagios server to send a 6 hour interval. But with my current set up it seems that the commands interval is set to 1 hour. Here is my default template for my servers monitoring and how I use it.

```
define host{
    name                            linux-vps           
    use                             generic-host            
    check_period                    24x7        
    check_interval                  5       
    retry_interval                  1       
    max_check_attempts              10      
    check_command                   check-host-alive
    notification_period             24x7    
    notification_interval           360      
    notification_options            d,r     
    contact_groups                  admins  
    register                        0                      
}

define host{
    use                             linux-vps
    host_name                       linux-server
    alias                           CentOS 6
    address                         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
}
```

On the Nagios server the config says the host notification interval is set to 6 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the alerts coming through service or host alerts? It could be that your service notification_interval is set to 1 hour.

Comment: Oh, good to know that they are separate objects, I don't have access right now to my Nagios server but I will update my post with my service definition.

Comment: If i set it directly in the service it seems to do the job. Although, according this [page](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectinheritance.html)  the service should inherit it from the host. @Will

Comment: do you have a "use" variable set at the top of the service? if so, it'll be inheriting the value from there, normally something like "use       linux_service".  if you don't use the "use" value then it will inherit it from the host definition

Comment: Ok, well my host has a 'use' variable that has a 'notification_interval' and my service don't have a 'use' variable but they do define a 'host'. Shouldn't this make it inherit from the host?

Comment: You were right after rechecking i was using the generic-service template on my services.